# how to take second column if first column not found in table in oracle DB

Tags: oracle, sys-refcursor

I'm expecting to write a query which takes second column if first column not found in table in oracle DB. In my case 'name' column is not present in table 'employees'

**NOTE** : I'm using reference cursor

I tried below,

query1:='select id or name,age from employees';

when I execute above statement, getting error

ORA-00904 "name": invalid identifier

ORA-06512 : at "employees", line 21

Comment: Relational table always have predefined structure, so at the time you are writing the code it's structure is known and fixed. There's no obvious reason to check column presence. Can you please elaborate more on what task you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly, I don't think you can (as you saw).

Though, you can `select * from employees` and it'll work:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_rc    sys_refcursor;
  3    l_row   dept%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    open l_rc for select * from dept;
  6    fetch l_rc into l_row;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, did you consider creating a `select` statement dynamically, by querying `user_tab_columns`? Something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str   varchar2(500);
  3    l_rc    sys_refcursor;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select column_name from user_tab_columns
  6                  where table_name = 'DEPT'
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      l_str := l_str || ', '|| cur_r.column_name;
 10    end loop;
 11
 12    l_str := 'select ' || ltrim(l_str, ', ') || ' from dept';
 13
 14    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 15
 16    open l_rc for l_str;
 17  end;
 18  /
select DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC from dept           --> this is the SELECT statement 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```